# Initial CSS Rule not Overwritten by Keyframe Animation in Webkit-Browsers under OS/iOS

Tags: ios, css, webkit, operating-system, css-animations

I have created a CSS3 keyframe animation to light up some candles as a little birthday greeting. The flame is created with pure CSS box-shadows and the :before pseudo element.

Animation:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
-moz-transform-origin: center bottom;
transform-origin: center bottom;
-webkit-animation: candle 25s ease-in 1 normal forwards;
-moz-animation: candle 25s ease-in 1 normal forwards;
animation: candle 25s ease-in 1 normal forwards;
```

Keyframes:

```
@keyframes candle{
0%{transform: scale(0,0);}
3%{transform: scale(0.3,0.2);}
9%{transform: scale(1,1.1);}
9.5%{opacity: 1;}
10%{transform: rotate(3deg);}
15%{transform: rotate(2deg);}
20%{transform: rotate(-6deg);}
25%{transform: rotate(3deg);}
30%{transform: rotate(2deg);}
35%{transform: rotate(-6deg);}
40%{transform: rotate(5deg);}
45%{transform: rotate(2deg);}
50%{transform: rotate(-3deg);}              
55%{transform: rotate(3deg);}
60%{transform: rotate(1deg);}
65%{transform: rotate(-4deg);}
70%{transform: rotate(3deg);}
75%{transform: rotate(2deg) scale(0.8,0.7);}
80%{transform: rotate(-2deg) scale(0.7,0.6); opacity: 1;}
85%{transform: rotate(5deg) scale(0.6,0.5);}
90%{transform: rotate(3deg) scale(0.5,0.4);}
95%{transform: rotate(-2deg) scale(0.4,0.3);}   
100%{transform: scale(0.3,0.2);}
}
```

Each flame has an individual delay and an initial opacity set to 0. The opacity is then overwritten by the keyframe animation.

See here: http://nymphenburg.netz-giraffe.de/

Now, this works fine in FF, Chrome, Explorer > 9 and so on. My only problem is, that is does NOT work with Webkit-Browsers under OS and iOS systems (including iPad and iPhone). It seems that only on those systems the opacity is not overwritten.

Does anyone have any clue how to fix this?